# Unable to unzip zip file using python 3.7.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I ran this below ..

#zip.py

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.Zipfile(r'\\v\region\na\appl\msim\im-eng\data\wolverine1\DST\test1.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip.ref.extractall(r'\\v\region\na\appl\msim\im-eng\data\wolverine2\DST')
```

---

This runs fine and I have no issue with unzipping this test1.zip.

But when I change the path to add this new zip file (ms_mli_statements_dlr_1637_062020.zip)

I am getting the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Clearly the file is there but I'm not sure what the issue is. Could anyone please help? I have been struggling with this for some time.

(running this on Pycharm using windows 10 btw)

Thank you.
Josh

Comment: Please share the code you used to extract the file **ms_mli_statements_dlr_1637_062020.zip**.

Comment: hey thanks for responding.. the code is the same I just changed the zip file from test1.zip to this one. (ms_mli_statements_dlr_1637_062020.zip) .

Comment: Okay.. then I am not able to get the reason for that... sorry